# Property was updated to initial value without any changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik, bindingsource

Cannot find why View update `ViewModel.ReceiveWarehouseID` after first changes of `ViewModel.Quantity`?
When form opened values are ok. If value of `RadSpinEditorQuantity` changed, then SelectedValue of `RadDropDownListWarehouses` changed to 0.
If SelectedValue of `RadDropDownListWarehouses` changed first - then everything woks normally.

I was used same approach with ViewModels and RadDropDownList controls before and never noticed this kind of behavior

Here my full code of Form and ViewModel - full, because I didn't find any code where value of `ReceiveWarehouseID` can be changed.

View(RadForm)

```vb
Public Sub New(viewmodel As Object)
    Me.InitializeComponent()

    Me.BindingSourceViewModel.DataSource = viewmodel
    Me.InitializeDataBindings()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeDataBindings()
    Me.RadLabelDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", 
                                            Me.BindingSourceViewModel, 
                                            "ItemDescription", 
                                            True, 
                                            DataSourceUpdateMode.Never)

    With Me.RadSpinEditorQuantity.DataBindings
        .Add("Value", Me.BindingSourceViewModel, "Quantity", True)
        .Add("Minimum", Me.BindingSourceViewModel, "MinQuantity", True)
        .Add("Maximum", Me.BindingSourceViewModel, "MaxQuantity", True)
    End With

    With Me.RadDropDownListWarehouses
        .DisplayMember = "Name"
        .ValueMember = "ID"
        .FormattingEnabled = True
        .DataMember = "WarehouseList"
        .DataSource = Me.BindingSourceViewModel
        .DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", 
                          Me.BindingSourceViewModel, 
                          "ReceiveWarehouseID", 
                          True, 
                          DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    End With
End Sub
```

ViewModel (Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

```vb
Public Sub New(original As OriginalRowViewModel)
    _Original = original 
    _Model = New RowTransfer() 'Here _Model.ReceiveWarehouseID set = 1
    Me.WarehouseList = Warehouse.GenerateList()
End Sub

Private _Original As OriginalRowViewModel
Private _Model As RowTransfer

Public Property Quantity As Decimal
    Get
        Return _Model.Quantity
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        If _Model.Quantity= value Then Exit Property
        _Model.Quantity= value
        Me.RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.Quantity)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ReceiveWarehouseID As Integer
    Get
        Return _Model.ReceiveWarehouseID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If _Model.ReceiveWarehouseID= value Then Exit Property
        _Model.ReceiveWarehouseID= value
        Me.RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.ReceiveWarehouseID)
    End Set
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property ItemDescription As String
     Get
        Return _Original.ItemDescription
     End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property MaxQuantity As Decimal
     Get
        Return _Original.FreeQuantity
     End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property MinQuantity As Decimal
     Get
        Return 1D
     End Get
  End Property

  Public Property WarehouseList As List(Of Warehouse)
```

**UPDATE**
If I set List of Warehouses straight to the `RadDropDownList` without `BindingSource`

```
RadDropDownList.DataSource = Warehouse.GenerateList()'
```

Or if I remove `Me.RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.PropertyName)` from setters of `Quantity` and `ReceiveWarehouseID`
Then everythings work ok.
But didn't want to do this, because same ViewModel will be used in the WPF window. And I try to make ViewModel which work for all views(Winforms and WPF) - keep List of warehouses in the ViewModel

```
Application.exe!Application.ViewModels.RowTransferViewModel.set_ReceiveWarehouseID(Integer value = 0)
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.dll!System.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object target, object[] args)
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(object component = {Application.ViewModels.RowTransferViewModel}, object value = 0)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetValue(object value)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PullData(bool reformat, bool force)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Binding.Target_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDropDownList.OnSelectedValueChanged(object sender, int newIndex, object oldValue, object newValue) 
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDropDownList.element_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDropDownListElement.OnSelectedValueChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDropDownListElement.NotifyOwner(Telerik.WinControls.UI.PopupEditorNotificationData notificationData)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.PopupEditorElement.listElement_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.OnSelectedValueChanged(int newIndex)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.OnSelectedIndexChanged(int newIndex)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.HandleSelectOne(int newIndex)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.ProcessSelection(int newIndex, bool onMouseDrag, Telerik.WinControls.UI.InputType inputType, int dir)  
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.dataLayer_CurrentPositionChanged(object sender,     Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListDataLayer.OnCurrentPositionChanged(int newPosition)
Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll!Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListDataLayer.CollectionView_CurrentChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
Telerik.WinControls.dll!Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadCollectionView<System.__Canon>.OnCurrentChanged(System.EventArgs args)
Telerik.WinControls.dll!Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadCollectionView<Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem>.SetCurrentPositionCore(int newPosition, bool forceNotify, Telerik.WinControls.CurrentChangeReason reason)
Telerik.WinControls.dll!Telerik.WinControls.Data.RadListSource<System.__Canon>.currencyManager_PositionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnPositionChanged(System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(int newPosition, bool validating, bool endCurrentEdit, bool firePositionChange, bool pullData)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.Position.set(int value)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.Position.set(int value)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ParentCurrencyManager_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnCurrentItemChanged(System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.InnerList_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<System.__Canon>.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Application.ViewModels.RowTransferViewModel>.Child_PropertyChanged(object sender,     System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
Application.exe!Application.ViewModels.ViewModelBase.RaisePropertyChanged(Of Decimal)(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Decimal)) kentta = {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Decimal))})
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Set a breakpoint in the setter for `ReceiveWarehouseID` and look at the call stack to see where the call came from.

Comment: Setter was triggered twice, first with same value, and second with new value = 0. I checked Stack - and noticed that after `Quantity` was changed BindingSource execute `ResetBindings` which ...added stack to the question